# connecting a mysql database using php to a host

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, host

Okay I'm having trouble connecting my database to my host..

Im using myPHPAdmin and I made a database on my host
the problem is in my php code where I define my connection to the host
everything worked fine when I did this on the localhost. 
But now that I want to use it on my personal domain it wont work 
it doesnt access the data in the database.
Im new at this so dont shoot me ;)

```
$connect = mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass");
```

so for my host/domain I enter my domain the-bloodgod.com ?

what do I enter for user and pass? is it just the login I normally use to access the Cpanel? Or do I have to create special permissions in myphpadmin?

also on my hosts myphpadmin it shows that it stores all created tables in the_bloodgod_com database collection

so would this be correct if I put it the code bellow?

```
mysql_select_db("the_bloodgod_com");
$sql="SELECT * FROM tablename";
```

Comment: Can you please follow this link to configure database:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_connect.asp


See the Example and Syntax. This should help you.

Comment: If correct, you received an email from your host with all relevant information. As put below by Big Chris, you use then a string to connect to. In your case, (and please use mysqli instead of mysql context within PHP, because its not safe to use) use your above context. `$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connect));`

Comment: @biswajitGhosh: don't link to w3fools. They're a horrible resource, their code is attrocious, and encourages many bad and dangerous programming habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOST hosting companies you have to use "localhost" as the host name for your database connection code. PHP:

`$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: alright thanks but now a dumb question, what about the username and password, should I use the normal login & pass which my host provided me to access my domain or do I have to make those in myphpadmin for permissions?

Comment: You should have already been given those details by your hosting company. By default, yes, it will most probably be the same username and password as your hosting login. Although you SHOULD create a separate user account with only the privileges your script requires. I.e. It should only need SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE at most! You could even create different users for different scripts - e.g. your "admin" panel user can have "DELETE" as an additional privilege, but your other scripts use a lesser role.